# Looking to have users check into booths at tradeshows

Tags: hashtag, checkin

Looking for a way to monitor what vendors users visit go to at trade shows. Then reward them for checking in at those vendors.... I am thinking of a picture match or a hashtag to define each vendor, but am not entirely sure this will work. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make a QR code with their contact details and write a android app that will scan and store who checks in.